# AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message

Tags: java, spring-security, saml-2.0

I am using spring saml authentication for SSO in my application. But the SAML Login is failing for me every time. Same configuration works fine at another machine.I am getting below exception:

```
org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationServiceException: Error validating SAML message
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(SAMLAuthenticationProvider.java:95)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:156)
    at org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLProcessingFilter.attemptAuthentication(SAMLProcessingFilter.java:84)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:166)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
...
```

Any idea?

Comment: Maybe you should add logging for the package **org.springframework.security**. Looking at the code in ´SAMLProcessingFilter´, the SAML message may be invalid or there is a problem with the provided metadata.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have added logging, but don't see any issue there. The main problem is I don't see any error either at my application side or at IDP. I have also tried with fiddler to check n/w issues. Any suggestion?

Comment: Did you set the log level for org.springframework.security to debug level? Normally, I would expect to see some more information coming from `SAMLProcessingFilter`. See:https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/saml/SAMLProcessingFilter.java